# How do I theme external hyperlinks differently with mkdocs?

Tags: mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I am using mkdocs with material theme and I am looking for a way to make all external links render differently than internal ones, so people will know when they point for external resources.

Wikipedia is a very good example of site that does represent external links with an extra icon after them, making navigation easier.

Comment: The `mkdocs-material` has the support of [tooltips](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/tooltips/#improved-tooltips).